# Django custom filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm new to django and I have a **plain text inserted from admin** and I wanted to user custom filter to **replace linebreak in plain text into new line**. I'm unable to see the changes of filter in browser

templatetags/filter.py

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='replace_linebr')
def replace_linebr(value):

    return str(value).replace('&#10;','&nbsp; &nbsp;')
```

Following filter works but I believe replace is not working

```
from urllib import quote_plus

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='replace_linebr')
def replace_linebr(value):

    return quote_plus(value)
```

my templates

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load filters %}

{% block blog_post %}
    <div class="blog-post">

        <p class="blog-post-title">{{ posts.title }}</p>
        <p class="blog-post-meta"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp {{ posts.pub_date|date  }}</i> </p>
        {{ posts.description|replace_linebr }}

    </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
{% endblock %}
```

My folder structure

[image]

settings.py
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `blog` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and it should work.

**Update**

You have typo, your python file is `filter.py` and in template you are doing `{% load filters %}`.

`{% load filters %}` should be `{% load filter %}`